# Casting Varchar2 to interval

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a configuration table such that I want to delete a row if the record_tm is over a certain configurable time (config_recordtrim_hrs). In other words, the variable recordtrim_config comes from another table where somebody writes a value (e.g. 24 for 24 hours) after which a record will be deleted.

```
DECLARE
recordtrim_flag configs_table.value%type;
recordtrim_config configs_table.value%type;
recordtrim_interval interval;
BEGIN
SELECT configs_table.value INTO recordtrim_flag FROM configs_table WHERE configs_table.name = 'enable_recordtrim';
SELECT configs_table.value INTO recordtrim_config FROM configs_table WHERE configs_table.name = 'config_recordtrim_hrs';
SELECT CAST (recordtrim_config AS interval) INTO recordtrim_interval;

IF (recordtrim_flag = 'T') THEN
DELETE FROM main_records WHERE record_tm + recordtrim_interval < current_timestamp;
END IF;
END;
```

This code throws an error at the line where I try to cast recordtrim_config as an interval. How do I fix this?

EDIT: My error:

> Error report: ORA-06550: line 8, column 40: PL/SQL: ORA-30089: missing
>   or invalid  ORA-06550: line 8, column 1: PL/SQL: SQL
>   Statement ignored

EDIT 2: New Code:

```
DECLARE
recordtrim_flag configs_table.value%type;
recordtrim_config configs_table.value%type;
recordtrim_interval interval;
BEGIN
SELECT configs_table.value INTO recordtrim_flag FROM configs_table WHERE configs_table.name = 'enable_recordtrim';
SELECT configs_table.value INTO recordtrim_config FROM configs_table WHERE configs_table.name = 'config_recordtrim_hrs';
recordtrim_interval := NUMTODSINTERVAL (recordtrim_config, 'HOUR');

IF (recordtrim_flag = 'T') THEN
DELETE FROM main_records WHERE record_tm + recordtrim_interval < current_timestamp;
END IF;
END;
```

New Error at line 11, recordtrim_interval is an invalid identifier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate cause of the error is that you've got just `interval` instead of the type, i.e. `interval day to second`. You also have to `select` from something - which can be `from dual` here, though a straight assignment is cleaner.

You can't cast it directly if it's a single number. Instead you can use the [`numtodsinterval` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/functions117.htm):

```
recordtrim_interval := NUMTODSINTERVAL (recordtrim_config, 'HOUR');
```

e.g.

```
set serveroutput on
declare
  recordtrim_config varchar2(4) := '24';
  recordtrim_interval interval day to second;
begin
  recordtrim_interval := NUMTODSINTERVAL (recordtrim_config, 'HOUR');
  dbms_output.put_line(recordtrim_interval);
end;
/

anonymous block completed
+01 00:00:00.000000
```

Or select that straight into the variable from the table.

If you need more complicated values, not a simple value that represents a number of hours - and if that was the case you'd store it as a number I assume - then if you store it in a suitable format, you can cast it, or use the [`to_dsinterval` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/functions204.htm) instead; any of these give the same result:

```
declare
  recordtrim_config varchar2(10) := '0 2:30:00';
  recordtrim_interval interval day to second;
begin
  recordtrim_interval := TO_DSINTERVAL (recordtrim_config);
  dbms_output.put_line(recordtrim_interval);
  SELECT CAST (recordtrim_config AS interval day to second)
  INTO recordtrim_interval from dual;
  dbms_output.put_line(recordtrim_interval);
  recordtrim_interval := CAST (recordtrim_config AS interval day to second);
  dbms_output.put_line(recordtrim_interval);
end;
/

anonymous block completed
+00 02:30:00.000000
+00 02:30:00.000000
+00 02:30:00.000000
```

---

In your edited question, the `ORA-00904: "RECORDTRIM_INTERVAL": invalid identifier` is only the last error in the list. Look back a bit and you'll see:

```
ORA-06550: line 4, column 21:
PLS-00201: identifier 'INTERVAL' must be declared
```

... followed by some other errors where you try to use the variable. Your declaration of the variable has to be:

```
recordtrim_interval interval day to second;
```

There is no '`interval`' data type; [they are `interval year to month` and `interval day to second`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/sql_elements001.htm#i54330).

Comment: I updated the original post with the error. Would this method work even though recordtrim_config is technically a varchar2 and not a number?

Comment: Also, when I type that in, my error is now on line 11, saying that recordtrim_interval is an invalid identifier

Comment: My problem is now with how I use recordtrim_interval in line 11. I want to delete the record when the timestamp in the record plus the recordtrim_interval is less than the current_timestamp

Comment: @KyleGrage - it would work if it's a varchar2 containing a single number (e.g. 24), as it would be implicitly case to the right type - that's what my example is doing. I've also added the more flexible `cast` and `to_dsinterval` options, but they require your config value to be in a strict format. Don't understand your line 11 error though, you seem to be using names consistently.

Comment: Ok, I think I found it, I added "day to second" after interval and it now works